# Restricting file types in AngularJS with HTML input type="file"

Tags: angularjs

So my HTML passes a file into AngularJS, and it is named as myFile. 
So I use:

```
console.log($scope.myFile.type);
```

and it prints out '*application/pdf*'.

But when I use this line:

```
if ($scope.myFile.type == 'application/pdf'){
    // some stuff here
    }
```

or

```
($scope.myFile.type == {'image/jpeg': fileMimeType})
```

Those will not ever be equal to true. I have no idea how to run this comparison anymore, and would appreciate snippets that would allow me to somehow create this comparison.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show html and function for calling this stuff? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I wish i could make comments, but alas i do not have enough points. Did you try `console.log( typeof $scope.myFile.type);` to make sure it was a string? Also did the output itself have single quotes in it? because if it does have the quotes in it you'll either need to strip those or compare with the quotes in your string.

Comment: Well, it printed "application/octet-stream".

Comment: yeah. I'm confused. I would expect that to be a string. Why would the type of the attribute of the object that's supposed to describe the filetype itself be a file/application?

Comment: I guess there might be more functions that you can use on this object to get it to string form, I'll try tinkering some more.